# Find the value in degrees for angle $S$.

Tags: geometry

[image]

My understanding: If we draw a line parallel to the given two lines, passing through $S$,then we get $S=a+a+40$. I don't know how to proceed further. Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the meaning of the adjective "acute", when referred to an angle?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli   Yes, 0<angle<90 degrees.

Comment: So, you learned $s=2a+40$.  Now, what happens if we take a perpendicular line to the parallel lines that passes through the vertex at $s$.  We'll have two right triangles.  One of the angles in a right triangle is $90^\circ$.  The other we should already know.  What is the missing angle in the created bottom right triangle?  The top?  Calling the missing angle from the bottom $b$ and from the top $t$, what should we know about $b+s+t$?

Comment: @Soumee Since you figured it out, be sure to write up and post your solution and reasoning here for anyone else in the future who has a question like this.

Comment: Also, as an aside, I find it rather odd that options (A),(C) and (D) are all "Quantity I > Quantity II"... shouldn't this have been included in the options only once?

Comment: @JMoravitz Sir, that should add up to 180 degrees. But if we write the equation 90-(a+40)+90-a+(a+40)+a=180, a gets cancelled!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$s=2a+40°\ \implies\ a={s\over2}-20°<{90°\over2}-20°=25°.$$

Comment: Sir, is there any way by which we can find the exact value of s or a? I can find the relation. But would like to know if the exact value of S could be found or not.

Comment: We cannot, without some other information.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

continue one of the lines inside to get a triangle with $(a,a+40,x) $ as its angles . then

$$a+a+40+x=180$$
$$x+s=180$$

from here
$$a+a+40+x+s=180+s$$
$$=a+a+40+180$$

and $$s=2a+40.$$

Comment: Maam is there any way by which we can find the exact value of s or a? I can find the relation. But would like to know if the exact value of S could be found or not...

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution:

If we draw the line conecting $a$ and $s$ we get a triangle (see the image below). The sum of the angles in triangle is 180°. So now we know (1):

$$a+(a+40°)+x=180°$$
we also know (2)
$$x+s=180°$$
because they make straight line.
Angle s is acute so (3)
$$s<90°$$

From the second equation we have
$$x=180°-s$$
we plug $x$ into the first equation
$$a+(a+40°)+180°-s=180°$$
subtract $180°$:
$$a+(a+40°)-s=0$$
add $s$
$$a+(a+40°)=s$$
We plug $s$ from the third equation and get:
$$a+(a+40°)<90°$$
we get rid of the brackets:
$$2a+40°<90°$$
And by subtracting 40° and dividing the equation by two we get an answer:
$$a<25°$$
B) is correct :)
[image: solution angle parallel lines]

Comment: SIR, is there any way by which we can find the exact value of s or a? I can find the relation. But would like to know if the exact value of S could be found or not..

Comment: No there is not. Any value of $S$ which lays between 0° and 90° will fit the problem assignment. If an exact value of $S$ was given then you could easily calculate exact value of $a$.